# Jquery trigger is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that performs auto click on ID

```
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#jivo-label-status').trigger('click');
        }, 5000)
    });
```

But it's not working and I don't know why, I tried to add $(document).ready, wrap it in function but no result. 
P.S. My jQuery library is loaded on site so it`s not a reason of problem

Comment: what does $('#jivo-label-status') return when you put it in the console?

Comment: What is #jivo-label-status? What's the HTML element?

Comment: What are you trying to trigger, it only works for jQuery bound event handlers ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `element.click();`.
It should work better.

Comment: element.click() is exactly the same as element.trigger("click")

Comment: Can I see the code, or at least the page? And what browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

can you look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/gfwSs/) and see if this is what you were looking for?

```
    $(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#jivo-label-status').trigger("click"); }, 500);
})

$('#jivo-label-status').on('click', function(){
    alert('Hello');
})
```